# PHP Xdebug Doesn't work in VSCode - Windows + IIS

Tags: php, iis, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have a problem with PHP Xdebug on VSCode.

My environment is Windows Server 2012 R2, I have installed VSCode and running IIS server with PHP 7.4, with Xdebug 3

When I open script with `xdebug_info()` from Firefox, then Xdebug log produces output. But when I hit F5 in VSCode there's no output (seems like extension doesn't connect with Xdebug at all).

VSCode config (it's default):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true,
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
        }
    ]
}
```

php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host=::1
xdebug.log = "c:\inetpub\xdebug_log.log"
```

VSCode debug output:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}
```

But I don't see any variable's values at all. Breakpoints doesn't work too.

When I try to call something in debug console, the output is:

```
Cannot evaluate code without a connection
```

Which could be inferred from no-log entries produced by VSCode requests. I spent about 4 hours about googling this problem, but couldn't find solution.

Comment: Are you sure that pressing "F5" starts the same PHP binary (with the same configuration file) as the PHP that is the back end of your web server? It's also possible that they use a different `php.ini` altogether.

Comment: It seems that I cannot use that at all. In every tutorial it was presented as "press F5 and VSCode executes php script at its own". I had to run this script with webbrowser with listening debugger on. Everything works fine.

Comment: Refer to the link to reconfigure vscode to use PHP Xdebug:https://www.srijan.net/blog/tutorial-using-xdebugger-with-php-vscode-to-debug